# Unable to Commit to Github: Permission denied

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, permissions

I have been following [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04) directions when it comes to installing Git onto my Ubuntu 14.4 machine and followed the [GitHub directions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) on how to obtain and save an ssh key pairing.

Right now I am trying to commit to the remote Github location by doing the following:

```
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 208 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:rsheeler/Ubuntu_Test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
```

It seems it's unable to access my GitHub location. To verify, I did the same command as mentioned only `sudo git push origin master` and got the following error `Permission denied (publickey)`.

In order to give more background, I created my ssh key in the following way:

```
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "rebeccasheeler@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/account/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:  
Your identification has been saved in /home/account/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/account/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:## rebeccasheeler@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
{little image here}
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 30342
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/beckah/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/beckah/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/beckah/.ssh/id_rsa)
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ sudo apt-get install xclip
[sudo] password for beckah: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xclip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 67.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe xclip i386 0.12+svn84-4 [16.5 kB]
Fetched 16.5 kB in 0s (113 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package xclip.
(Reading database ... 194616 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xclip_0.12+svn84-4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking xclip (0.12+svn84-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up xclip (0.12+svn84-4) ...
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
Hi rsheeler! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ sudo git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ git remote add origin git@github.com:rsheeler/Ubuntu_Test.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
beckah@the-tank:/git/testing$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 208 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:rsheeler/Ubuntu_Test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
```

As seen by when I copied the ssh key with **xcut**, I pasted the key into the *SSH Key* section of my account on GitHub.

I have also tried to look at the following questions on the forum

https://askubuntu.com/questions/137165/git-ssh-permission-denied-publickey

https://askubuntu.com/questions/267392/using-authorized-keys-with-git

---

**EDIT:** I tried to see if the error was occurring locally by granting read/write permission to the user `beckah` through opening the folder and using `chown -R beckah .` and then trying to grant read/write access to the folder for all users with `chmod 777 -R testing/`. Both of  them still rendered permission errors when I tried to commit to the project after.

Comment: Go into you local source directory which I guess it `/git/hosting` . Then in that directory issue the command `sudo chown -R beckah .`  It appears from the output your account is `beckah`. Then try your git push again. I think this is a local permission problem (not a remote one)

Answer (score 1):

Although one would think from the output that this is a remote permission issue I think it is local. It appears from the output that your SSH key on the server was registered fine.

Likely the permissions locally are incorrect and some are not for your current user account (Just a guess). To fix that go into your `/git/testing` directory and issue this command:

```
sudo chown -R beckah .
```

This will make sure the `beckah` user has ownership on all the files (recursively) in the local repository.

The above should be okay if you are the only person on the system who uses the `/git` directory. If `/git` is a directory that you share with other users on your Ubuntu system then you will have to consider creating a new group and adding yourself to it. Then give group ownership to that group across your entire `/git` directory tree with read and write privs.

Comment: this didn't seem to work. :/

I did the following commands from the folder: `sudo chown -R beckah .` Then when I tried to do `sudo git push origin master` I got the error message `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` I then tried to give all accounts read and write access to the testing folder by using the chmod command or `chmod 777 -R testing/` but still got the permission error :L

Comment: Okay next question. Is `rsheeler` the actual account you have set up at github?

Comment: Yes. That is the actually account.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: `origin git@github.com:rsheeler/Ubuntu_Test.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:rsheeler/Ubuntu_Test.git (push)
`

Comment: Does rsheeler account have privileges (via the github webpage) to read/write this project?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I'm the author of the project and simply created it as a test to make sure git was working on my computer https://github.com/rsheeler/Ubuntu_Test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60656/discussion-between-michael-petch-and-rsheeler).

Answer (score -1):

you have been logged into other github account so it is not letting to commit to github user account that is not logged in

Comment: Please suggest solutions for the author to fix the issue.